# List of users that not yet in any role, (MVC4 with SimpleMembership and entity framework 5)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, roles, simplemembership

I am using mvc 4 with entity framework. I need a list of all users that have not yet been assigned any role. I cannot find any predefined function in Role.

[image]

Output will be.

[image]

My current code is as following.

```
var users = db.UserProfileEFMs
    .ToList()
    .Where(o => !Roles.GetRolesForUser(o.UserName).ToList<string>().Any())
    .ToList();
```

but it is not working properly or is too slow. 
Is there any another way to get that kind of list.

I am looking for an Extentions method for Roles like.

```
public static class Extentions
{
public static List<string>/*UserName*/ UsersNotInAnyRole(this Roles /*System.Web.Security*/ roles)
{
    /*----code----*/
}
}
```

currently i am using the following code

```
var users = db.Database.SqlQuery<UserProfile>("select * from dbo.UserProfile where UserId not in(select UserId from dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles)").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get better solution. I think following is the best one.

```
var users = db.Database.SqlQuery<UserProfile>("select * from dbo.UserProfile where UserId not in(select UserId from dbo.webpages_UsersInRoles)").ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call `ToList()` so much - the following code is equivalent to what you have.

```
var users = db.UserProfileEFMs
    .Where(o => !Roles.GetRolesForUser(o.UserName).Any())
    .ToList();
```

The first `ToList()` is not needed because you're going to evaluate all the items in `db.UserProfileEFMs` anyway.

The second `ToList<string>()` forces the evaluation of all of the values of `GetRolesForUser`, even though you only care if there are any, which is wasteful.

---

Have you tried splitting this into `foreach` loops and profiling it, e.g.

```
var users = new List<T>;
foreach ( var userProfileEFM in db.UserProfileEFMs)
{
    if ( !Roles.GetRolesForUser(userProfileEFM.UserName).Any() )
        users.Add(userProfileEFM)
}
```

where `T` is the type of the items in `db.UserProfileEFMs`.

Comment: I got an error. LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String[] GetRolesForUser(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: On which line is that?

Comment: ... I've not used LINQ to Entities so the `foreach` method may not help.